# Quicklook Webarchive?

Tags: xcode, macos

Currently writing an app that should be able to quicklook webarchive. Copied data from safari also happens to be saved as .webarchive.
Is there a way to show them ? Or do I need to convert the webarchive, or by extracting html first ?

Comment: Any news on your project? The native Quicklook in macOS 11 Big Sur is still not able to render webarchive files properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the WebArchive class from WebKit or my open source implementation DTWebArchive: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTWebArchive

This gives you access to the individual parts that make up the web archive, which is essentially just a binary plist.